# How can we flow user session from one spring application context to another?

Tags: spring, security, session, sharing, applicationcontext

How can we flow user session from one spring application context to another?
Basically I have one spring application representing Web Layer and another spring application representing REST layer.  I want when Web Layer access the REST layer the session containing user info to be available from to Web at REST layer for authentication.

Please suggest.

*Edit after receiving first ans:* 
At present we do have Web Layer in place along with security and all the other flows.  What we are about to intended is to introduce REST layer.  This REST layer is suppose to be called by present Web Layer and by other APIs.  We do not want to make any changes for Web Layer, but at the same time need security to be placed at REST Layer that should work for Web Layer too when calling REST services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiate between SSO and session sharing. If you just want the authentication to carry between application (user only has to log in once), then you want some form of Single-Sign-On (SSO), [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) is one example, but there are numerous.

If, on the other hand, you need to have access to the full session (and everything the application has put in it) across different nodes (or applications), you could look into something like [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [Terracotta](http://ehcache.org/documentation/distributed_caching_with_terracotta.html). Worth noting is that session replication is fairly I/O intensive and for larger sites it often requires a dedicated network interface for the replication.

I would put it to you, however, that if your applications are so tightly coupled that they need to share the same exact session state, then perhaps they should not be separated in the first place? This smells of faulty design and architecture assumptions.